# Conditional proxy server in python/perl/shell script

Tags: python, perl, http, shell, proxy

I've an application which queries a hostName:port for some service, a webservice. During development some of the services are not available or under construction by a third party, hence to develop our application I'm thinking of using mockservices with soapUI as a stub for some services.

Problem is I can point my application only in one direction once, so if I point to the mockservice, I need to make sure the mockservice is emulating **all** the services (>50), this is too much overhead. Hence I was thinking of pointing my application to a proxy server which would redirect some requests to the mockservices and remaining to the actual service provider. Is there any way I could do this through a simple script?

Comment: "I can point my application only in one direction once" -- what does that mean?

Comment: @shx2 I've the webService url configured in a properties file like "xyzServiceProvider.uri=https:/ /abc:8080"

Answer (score 2):

Sure. A rough sketch using Perl:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Plack::App::Proxy;

my $live_proxy = Plack::App::Proxy->new(
    remote => "http://live.soap.service.com:80/"
);

my $soapui_proxy = Plack::App::Proxy->new(
    remote => "http://localhost:4567/"
);

sub {
    my $env = shift;
    if ($env->{REQUEST_URI} =~ m[^/some/path]) {
        return $soapui_proxy->($env);
    } else {
        return $live_proxy->($env);
    }
};
```

install [Plack](http://p3rl.org/Plack) and run it as `plackup filename`.  It constructs two proxy apps, one which forwards all requests to the live service URL, and one which forwards all requests to your mock service URL. Then the wrapper app chooses which app to dispatch any given request to based on the URL (or based on something else, if need be).

Comment: Thanks :) unfortunately I just found out I'm not allowed to install Plack, will have to look for a different way.

Comment: @Rnet any common webserver (apache, nginx, lighttpd, and probably many others) could be configured to do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I'm setting up nginx reverse proxy, accepting your comment as ans :)